# Changing URL / Moving document Libraries with Powershell

Tags: 2010, document-library, powershell, path

I have 100s of Document Libraries with documents in them. 
The path is: CustomerNumbers/Lists/Documents, I would like to move them 1 folder out; to  CustomerNumbers/Documents.

All metadata must be retained.

Can I do this with PowerShell ? 
Any resources on the web that can help me to?

Comment: yes you can do this on powershell but you need have the permission

Comment: thanks, have you done this before or know someone who has? Do I simply copy them to the desired destination or is it a simple command to "move" the files.

Comment: Copy from one folder to the other folder. BTW you will lose all your versions. Do u need code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two ways to do that:

First : **The easiest**: Navigate to the source document library and open the "explorer view" then copy the documents and move those to the new path

Second: Type a script or program

```
$src       = $web.Lists [ "source" ]
$dest      = $web.Lists [ "dest" ]
$destFiles = $dest.Folders [ "mydoc" ]
foreach ( $item in $srcLibrary.Items )
{ 
   if ( $item.File )
   {
        $file = $item.file.OpenBinary()
        $destURL = $destFiles.Folder.Url + "/" + $item.file.Name 
        $destFiles.Add ( $destURL, $file, $true )
    }
}
```

BTW You will lost all your versions if the version option was enabled

Comment: @lwbecker2 I still waiting a integration between stackexchange and gits :)